# How to deploy base on multiple branch?

Tags: deployment, appveyor

I am using appveyor to publish packages to nuget, I would like to do the publish if the branch is either `master` or `dev`, my current settings is

```
deploy:
  provider: NuGet
  on:
    branch: master
```

How can I add `dev` branch?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using regex, here is what i got

`on:
    branch: /^(master|dev)$/`

Comment: You can also do this other way around as described [here](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/branches/#sharing-common-configuration-between-branches), but this will result in more complicated YAML and makes sense if you have others branch-specific settings.